# Spam Detector: Detect spam posts! (section just to test it: 736-_555 /007//] [3)

Tags: app

Note: There is something in the title to test this tool.

#### About: (required)

This searches for spam on a given site and places the links in an MD file.

#### Screenshot / Code Snippet:  (highly recommended)

```python
# Imports not included

def get_spam(site: str = "stackoverflow") -> str:
  true = True
  false = False
  json = eval(requests.get(f"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/questions?page=1&pagesize=30&order=desc&sort=creation&site={site}&filter=!Fc6b9*tI0e7rqpMIoRUAgp8tJ8").text)['items']
  spam = [x for x in json if re.search(r'(?:\d-*){10}', x['link'])]
  return '\n'.join(x['link'] for x in spam)
```

#### Download / Install: (required)

Fork or clone [this repo](https://github.com/PlaceReporter99/SE_Spam_Detector), change `sitename.txt` to the desired site and run the workflow. It will also be run when `current_minute % 5 == 4`. To stop this, you can comment out the `schedule:` and `- cron:` lines.

#### Platform: (recommended)

Works on GitHub.

#### Contact: (optional)

Just me. Open a discussion if you want to contact me. Note that discussions are public.

#### License: (optional)

Not under a license yet.

#### Code: (recommended)

Just used the `requests` module in Python to query from the API. You can contribute by forking and opening a pull request.

Comment: [SmokeDetector](https://charcoal-se.org/#whats-smokey) usually handles these as well as *many* other patterns for spam.

Comment: It baffles me why SE code itself does not detect phone numbers and flag them as suspected spam, only visible in review queues.  Do I need to install python to run it ?

Comment: @RohitGupta GitHub actions should install it for you. I just fixed a bug a few minutes ago, so try running the action again.